# Comparação entre letras

Tags: c

Consegui fazer com que uma letra digitada pelo usuário, seja mostrada outro

**Exemplo:** c retorna A, pois a letra A é a que mais vezes se usa nosso alfabeto. Assim eu posso desvendar uma mensagem por exemplo, pois na mensagem a letra que mais sai é C, então C virou A.

Só que tem letras que tem a mesma quantidade de vezes que se repetem, por exemplo j,g com 10 cada. A pergunta é como fazer para que seja alocado a letra j e depois a g, tipo um peso para uma delas.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
main()
{
char chave[26],texto[30],frase[30];

int cont,i;

printf("Digite o texto: ");
scanf("%s",chave);

cont=strlen(chave);
strcpy(texto, chave);  

for(i=0;i<cont;i++)     
{
    if (texto[i]=='c')
        frase[i]='a';      

    else if (texto[i]=='z')
        frase[i]='e';
    else if (texto[i]=='s')
        frase[i]='o';
    else if (texto[i]=='m')
        frase[i]='r';
        else if (texto[i]=='n')
        frase[i]='n';
        else if (texto[i]=='e')
        frase[i]='z';
        else if (texto[i]=='j')
        frase[i]='d';
        else if (texto[i]=='a')
        frase[i]='w';           

    else frase[i]=texto[i];
} 
printf("\n %s\nTexto Descriptografada e :\n %s\n", chave, frase);  
}
```

Comment: Amigo, tua questão não está clara. O que exatamente tu precisas?

Comment: Como assim peso para as letras G e J? Queres atribuir valor inteiro? (isso não pode, só é possível talvez representa-los em string talvez)

Comment: seria como se fosse descriptografar um código, onde a chave seria as letras que mais saim em português, dai cada letra do código recebe a letra mais acessada, exemplo, se no texto a ser descriptografado  é. xxxaattt, o X recebe A, pois A é a primeira letra que mais aparece, só que como eu faço para a letra A e T, pois as duas tem o mesmo numero nesse texto a ser convertido

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Substituição em c](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/293180/substitui%c3%a7%c3%a3o-em-c)

Comment: Ainda não tá claro. Para comparar letras, basta ver se possuem o mesmo código. Contar ocorrências em um texto, tu usas um loop e um contador. Mas agora, se teu problema é como implementar um decodificador, tua questão é ampla demais (e a lógica que colocaste no comentário não é confiável)

Comment: teria alguma Pdf de como fazer isso, sou iniciante em C